# How to call my toast (native-base) anywhere of my code?

Tags: react-native

I am using base-native (https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#toast-def-headref) with this code a toast is generated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Toast, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
export default class ToastExample extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Container>
    <Header />
    <Content padder>
      <Button onPress={()=> Toast.show({
          text: 'Wrong password!',
          buttonText: 'Okay'
        })}>
        <Text>Toast</Text>
      </Button>
    </Content>
  </Container>
 );
 }
}
```

I want to call it from anywhere in my code, for example

```
handlerToast= ()=>{
 Toast.show({
  text: 'Wrong password!',
  buttonText: 'Okay'
 })
}
```

If I put it into a function I get errors,like this:

[image]

```
<Button onPress={()=> this.handlerToast()}
</Button>
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in native base [doc](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#toast-def-headref) :

> For Toast to work, you need to wrap your topmost component inside  from native-base.

So, wrap your topmost component with native base `<Root>` as below :

```js
import { Root } from "native-base";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Page: { screen: Page },
  }
);
export default () =>
  <Root>
    <AppNavigator />
  </Root>;
```

Comment: I don't have my computer with me, but is this the only thing I should do? With this my code will work?

Answer (score 1):

In recent version of native-base NativeBaseProvider
is used instead of Root

```
import {NativeBaseProvider} from 'native-base';
   export default () =>
     <NativeBaseProvider>
       <App/>
     </NativeBaseProvider>;
```